# Call derived function from base contract

Tags: solidity, override

I have the following smart contracts:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract base {
    uint public v;
    separate public mySep;

    function base() {
        mySep = new separate();
    }

    function f() {
        v = 1;
    }

    function sepCall() {
        mySep.doStuff();
    }
}

contract derived is base{
    function f() {
        v = 2;
        super.f();
    }
}

contract separate {
    derived myBase;

    function separate() {
        // constructor expects to be called by base or derived
        myBase = derived(msg.sender);
    }

    function doStuff() {
        myBase.f();
    }
}
```

I only create an instance of `derived` which I expect to do the following:

1. call base constructor `base()`
2. base constructor creates instance `mySep` of `separate` contract

Now I am calling `sepCall` of that `derived` instance which I expected to do the following:

3. it calls the `doStuff` function of the `separate` contract.
4. the `doStuff` calls the overridden function `f` **of the `derived` contract** (since that's its type)

The last point is not happening, after calling `sepCall` of the `derived` instance its value `v` is 1 and not 2 which it would be if the overridden function of `derived` would have been called.

This might not be solidity related but a general JS issue but I'd like to find out how I could make `sepCall` invoke the overridden function `f` that sets `v` to 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading your code, V = 1, because after you set V=2 you then call super.f() which sets it to 1.

Comment: thank you for solving this fake mystery! Then indeed everything behaves as expected.

Comment: You are welcome, I like a challenge :D